# What is the new option ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING in Xcode 15?

Tags: xcode

After downloading the [Xcode 15 beta](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes) and running my project, I get a warning to update the project to recommended settings with

> Enable User Script Sandboxing
>
> Enabling user script sandboxing is recommended to ensure correctness of the build. This will enable the
> ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING build setting.

What are the implications? When should it enabled/disabled? What if I have i.e. [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen) set as a build phase?

Comment: I was using React Native and the `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` phase was giving rsync errors. It happened after I enabled those project recommendations. So if you are having issues and you enabled it, try to remove it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it gives problems for your project, you can simply change ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = YES back to NO in project.pbxproj if needed.
In the Xcode GUI it is a boolean pick list or ASCII text (depending what you select for "open as".

I tried the recommended YES setting on my own project, but I got complaints that my case (SwiftLint) was trying to *read* some non-Swift files. These were .git, .github, projectname.xcodeproj and a file related to string localisation. Clearly none of these 4 files were .swift files, so SwiftLint was over-zealous in opening these 4 files. And Xcode was more-or-less right to cause the build to fail when SwiftLint runs in a sandbox.

Surprisingly, I didn't find others complaining about this yet. But I expect SwiftLint will address this during the Xcode 14 beta phase.

[Where to change the setting, and the error messages that I got. Ignore the 6779 number - probably a line number rather than an error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs04m.png)

Comment: Yeah, I get this problem with RSwift too

Comment: Linters are like cancer. They spread over space and time until everything is under their sphere of influence.

Answer (score 2):

> User Script Sandboxing
> Setting name: [ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXIN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference#User-Script-Sandboxing)G
>
> If enabled, the build system will sandbox user scripts to disallow undeclared input/output dependencies.

A typical error like this:

```
Sandbox: swiftlint(97252) deny(1) file-read-data /YourProject/.swiftlint.yml
```

is solved with

```
Input Files
$(SRCROOT)/.swiftlint.yml
```

But for a whole list of files you can do

```
Input File Lists
$(SRCROOT)/inputFiles.xcfilelist
```

which you can create with

```
find . \( -name "*.swift" -o -name ".swiftlint.yml" \) > inputFiles.xcfilelist
```

But this is still a problem, how can you create the list of files on every compilation?

Comment: Even with the pattern, you can get error when having too many files: "pattern serialization length xxxxx exceeds maximum (65535)

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 15, it indicates a recommendation to run user-defined scripts within a sandboxed environment during the build process.
It was appeared in Xcode15 for me too.
This prevents the scripts from making unintended changes to the system, thus improving the stability and security of the build.
I recommend to say 'yes' for this setting.